# Google-Ads API broke all of the sudden with: `error_remapped_callable googleads`

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

My python code which calls the Google-Ads API broke. I guess because of a deprecation - but I cannot see the problem. As the cloud log is truncated.

Any idea how to fix this/investigate more?

```
   accessible_customers = customer_service.list_accessible_customers()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/ads/googleads/v13/services/services/customer_service/client.py", line 536, in list_accessible_customers
    response = rpc(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 72, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 247, in __call__
    response, ignored_call = self._with_call(request,
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 290, in _with_call
    return call.result(), call
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 146, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 274, in continuation
    response, call = self._thunk(new_method).with_call(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 301, in with_call
    return self._with_call(request,
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 290, in _with_call
    return call.result(), call
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 146, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 274, in continuation
    response, call = self._thunk(new_method).with_call(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 301, in with_call
    return self._with_call(request,
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_interceptor.py", line 287, in _with_call
    call = self._interceptor.intercept_unary_unary(continuation,
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/ads/googleads/interceptors/exception_interceptor.py", line 99, in intercept_unary_unary
    self._handle_grpc_failure(response)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/ads/googleads/interceptors/exception_interceptor.py", line 71, in _handle_grpc_failure
    raise self._get_error_from_response(response)
google.ads.googleads.errors.GoogleAdsException: (<_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:"
```

[image]